# Best way to perform a bubble sort in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Every time I learn a new language, I try to build a bubble sort in it. I do this because it uses a good portion of common iteration, so that I can reference it later on.

Now, in every other language that I've tried this in (C, Python, VB) this has been (at most) a 20 minute task... (bar from C, where I encountered memory allocation problems).

But in Ruby... I just can't get this to work. I've followed the exact same formula which I have always used. Without further ado:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

unsorted = []
swapFlag = 0
count    = 1   # 1 == TRUE, 0 == FALSE
temp     = 0

# Fills array with random numbers
while count != 20
  count += 1
  unsorted[count]=rand(100)
end

# Prints unsorted numbers, for comparison
while count != 0
  print "#{count} #{unsorted[count]} \n"
  count -= 1 
end

print "\n"

limit = unsorted.length


# This section is the problem.
# I'm assuming it's got something to do with the logic of the loop

while swapFlag == 1
  swapFlag = 0
  for count in 1..limit 
    if unsorted[count] > unsorted[count + 1]
      temp = unsorted[count + 1]
      unsorted[count + 1] = unsorted[count]
      unsorted[count] = temp
      swapFlag = 1
    end
  end     
end

count = 0
while count != 20 
  count += 1
  print "#{count} - #{unsorted[count]} \n"
end
```

I have tried using different if loop syntax, using the .each do method ... to no avail.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "can't get this to work". Are you perchance getting the exception `"ArgumentError (comparison of Integer with nil failed)"`? When `count = limit - 1`, `if unsorted[count] > unsorted[count + 1]` reduces to `if unsorted[count] > nil`, as the last element of `unsorted` has index `limit - 1`. When you have an exception you need to report precisely what it was and on what line it occurred. That often pinpoints your problem.

Comment: "I just can't get this to work." is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Once you get your code fixed you  should posted it at SO's sister-site, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There you will receive helpful advice on how to improve your code (and make it more Ruby-like). For one, *for loops* are *never* used, for reasons you will come to understand.

Comment: As an aside, Ruby has a nifty feature called [multiple assignment](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment) (aka *parallel assignment*) that allows you to write `unsorted[count], unsorted[count + 1] = unsorted[count + 1], unsorted[count]`. In effect, it employs your `temp` variable under the covers in performing the swap.

Comment: Sincere apologies for the lack of description. I appreciate entirely that Ruby is object oriented, which of course warrants a totally different style of programming. I plan on first getting the basic formula working, before then proceeding to integrate some of the benefits of the language.

Comment: The problem at first was that the loop was never entered, and thus never sorted. I've now managed to get into the loop, but am now receiving this error:

./bubbleSort.rb:24:in `block in <main>': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from ./bubbleSort.rb:23:in `each'
 from ./bubbleSort.rb:23:in `<main>'

Comment: The error message says the method `<`'s receiver is `nil` and `nil` doesn't have a method `<`, so somewhere you have `e <...` where `e` is an expression that evaluates to `nil`. Is line 23 `unsorted[count + 1] = unsorted[count]`? If so check if `count` equals `limit-1` when the exception is raised, which would make `unsorted[count + 1` equal `nil`. If necessary add  `puts "count=#{count}"` before that line and rerun your code.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to not even enter the `while` loop:

```
swapFlag = 0
...
while swapFlag == 1
```

Also, this code may work when you fix it, but it's just not Ruby-like. This method of learning may be fine to understand syntax and some basic iterations, but the language offers so much more functional, readable and powerful ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: Sure enough, but you might expand your answer to point out other problems, to give Lewis his money's worth.

Comment: Brilliant, I completely neglected that! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

## The swapflag is never set to 1

```
while swapFlag == 1  # <------ HERE IS YOUR BUG, the swapFlag is never set to 1!!!
  swapFlag = 0
  for count in 1..limit 
    if unsorted[count] > unsorted[count + 1]
      temp = unsorted[count + 1]
      unsorted[count + 1] = unsorted[count]
      unsorted[count] = temp
      swapFlag = 1
    end
  end     
end
```